# Stockfish 12 source code: Templates replacing function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, bitboard

Since [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/) is the highest rated chess engine, and it's known to be quite CPU-effiecient I decided to open its source code and try to understand and see how it works.

I came across this snippet of code, simply shifts a bitboard to a certain direction (north, south, east...)

**TAKEN FROM STOCKFISH 12 SOURCE: [**Download**](https://stockfishchess.org/download/)**

```cpp
template<Direction D>
constexpr Bitboard shift(Bitboard b) {
  return  D == NORTH      ?  b             << 8 : D == SOUTH      ?  b             >> 8
  // ...........
}
// Bitboard is a type definition for uint64_t
```

Calling the function

```cpp
shift< direction >(bitboard);
```

What is the need to have a template in this context, and why would something like

```cpp
constexpr Bitboard shift(Bitboard b,Direction D) {
  return  D == NORTH      ?  b             << 8 : D == SOUTH      ?  b             >> 8
  // ...........
}
```

not work? Is the first way more efficient in any way?

Comment: "Is the first way more efficient in any way?" Yes.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. can you put "why" in an answer

Comment: @AryanParekh `D` is evalueated at compile time in the template case, that's why it's more efficient (by means of performance).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ does that mean It's always better to use this compared to the 2nd method? I 'd appreciate it if you could put the info in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the need to have a template in this context, and why would something like
>
> ```
> // omitted code
> ```
>
> not work?

The version with the parameter given will work as well.

> Is the first way more efficient in any way?

Yes, using the template will be more efficient, since `D` is always evaluated at compile time, as it's a `constexpr`.

Evaluating at runtime would always require a function call (though it could be inlined), and evaluation of the parameter from the stack (which may cost a few register operations, even if inlined).